# How to bind std::list<int> to a Python type using Pybind11

Tags: c++, pybind11

As mentioned in [Pybind11 documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html#binding-stl-containers), for binding the STL containers, one can do something like this:

```
#include <pybind11/stl_bind.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>

PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<int>);
    
// later in binding code:
py::bind_vector<std::vector<int>>(m, "VectorInt");
```

Using this definition, I can easily wrap a function that returns a `std::vector<int>` and call it from Python.

But the question is, what should I do for a function that returns a `std::list<int>`? How can I introduce this type to `Pybind11`? It seems that there is no `py::bind_list<std::list<int>>` method. And if I try to introduce it using `bind_vector`, like:

```
py::bind_vector<std::list<int>>(py_module, "ListInt", pybind11::module_local(false));
```

apparently, I see compilation error(s) on this line of code, noting that the specified type is not a `std::vector`. Without this definition, I cannot call my method from Python:

```
>>> l = returnIntList(3)
TypeError: Unregistered type : std::list<int,std::allocator<int> >

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Unable to convert function return value to a Python type! The signature was
        (arg0: int) -> std::list<int,std::allocator<int> >
```

Am I missing anything in the documentation?

p.s. In the automatic tests of the Pybind library regarding [the bindings](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/tests/test_stl_binders.cpp) and [stl containers](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/blob/master/tests/test_stl.cpp), I see no example of `std::list` as the return value.

Comment: I don't think it is supported. You can always export `std::list<int>` as a custom Python class as shown [here](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html?highlight=std%3A%3Alist#making-opaque-types).

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit Well, in that case, transforming of std::list<int>  into std::vector<int> would be easier (should pay the conversion cost), no?

Comment: The whole point of binding the containers is that they are live objects, you can manipulate them python-side and see the effects of that C++-side. Converting a list to a vector defeats the purpose.

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit True. In that case, what does the first paragraph of [the documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html?highlight=std%3A%3Alist#making-opaque-types) mean? "When including the additional header file pybind11/stl.h, conversions between `std::vector<>`/`std::deque<>`/`std::list<>`/`std::array<>`/std::valarray<>, std::set<>/std::unordered_set<>, and `std::map<>`/`std::unordered_map<>` and the Python `list`, `set` and `dict` data structures are automatically enabled."

Comment: @n.m.willseey'allonReddit As you see, the automatic conversion of `std::list<>` is explicitly mentioned in the documentation. Am I understanding it wrongly??

Comment: Automatic conversion is different from binding. You can convert an std::list *value* to a Python list, but you cannot *bind*   an std::list *variable* to a Python list.